# Not able to build Raft implementation of LogCabin using scons and Protobuf 3

Tags: c++, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, scons, raft

I am not able to build RAFT implementation of LogCabin (C++) using scons and protobuf3 in Ubuntu.

Errors be like

```
usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h: In member function ‘int google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<Element>::SpaceUsedExcludingSelf() const’:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:888:12: error: ‘ToIntSize’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
    return internal::ToIntSize(SpaceUsedExcludingSelfLong());
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map.h:48:0,from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h:34,               from ./build/Protocol/ServerStats.pb.h:25, from build/Tree/Tree.cc:19:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h: In static member function ‘static void google::protobuf::internal::MapTypeHandler<(google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)9u, Type>::Clear(google::protobuf::internal::MapTypeHandler<(google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)9u, Type>::TypeOnMemory*, google::protobuf::Arena*)’:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h:638:1: error: ‘GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited’ is not a member of ‘google::protobuf::internal’
 STRING_OR_BYTES_HANDLER_FUNCTIONS(STRING)
```

Please suggest how do I proceed.!

Comment: Can you paste the compiler command line as well? (Or even better the whole build log)

Comment: Build log is huge so not posting it here. For compilation I used "scons". I followed instructions on https://github.com/logcabin/logcabin.

Comment: Does your build environment meet the list of requirements in the README? (Maybe you have an unsupported version of protobuf?)